# R: How to loop a query to avoid a server (BOLD) overload

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, server, range

I'm a home-based 1st year PhD student relying on minimal support during the pandemic. I would thank you for your guidance in this topic.

-I have a dataframe called `spsp`. In this dataframe I have a column (or variable) called `BOLDQUERY` which has a length of 7030 species names or observations
(`spsp$BOLDQUERY`)

-The server I want to inquire is called BOLD. Which is similar to NCBI but for barcodes.
(`library(bold)`)

but the BOLD server will only accept **100 queries at a time before overloading**, and not return any query.

I want to split the **BOLDQUERY** variable in chunks of 100 observations and then print a table from the results of my query to the BOLD server.

**e.g. for observation 1 to 100**

```
spspbold1.100 <- tbl_df(bold_specimens(taxon = spsp$BOLDQUERY[1:100], geo = "Italy"

write.csv2(spspbold1.100, "spsp1.100.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

but to cover all observations this would mean splitting the variable BOLDQUERY into aprox(7030/100) **71** pieces and typing the range 71 times.

There has to be a loop that can avoid retyping ranges 71 times,
How would you loop this process?
I would really appreciate your guidance in the right direction.
I'm a beginner coder in R.

Many thanks!

---

**THE INEFICIENT WAY OF DOING THIS:**

**MANUALLY TYPING AND SPLITING **BOLDQUERY** INTO BITS OF 100 observation UNTIL I REACH 7030, or at least 7000**

```
library(bold)

library(tidyverse)

spspbold1.100 <- tbl_df(bold_specimens(taxon = spsp$BOLDQUERY[1:100], geo = "Italy"))

write.csv2(spspbold1.100, "spspbold1.100.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

.

69 times

.

.

```
spspbold6901.7000 <- tbl_df(bold_specimens(taxon = spsp$BOLDQUERY[6901:7000], geo = "Italy"))

write.csv2(spspbold6901.7000 "spspbold6901.7000.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

---

**IN THE LOOP I WANT TO CREATE**

I want to query the same ranges, e.g:
1 to 100,
101 to 200,
201 to 300,
.
.
.
until 7030.

then define:

```
k<- 1 

j<- 0:round(n/100) #0 to 70

l<- 1:ceiling(n/100) #1 to 71

library(tidyverse)

##number of observations in BOLDQUERY

n <- as.numeric(spsp %>% 
  select(BOLDQUERY) %>% 
  summarise(
    n()
  ))
```

The lower and upper limits of a 1:100 and range could behave according to the following equation

**-equation for lower limit (ll = k*1 +100j)**

where
1 = 1*(k=1) +100(j=0), where k=1 (always) and j has a range from [0;round(n/100)]

**-equation for upper limit (ul = 100*l)**

where 100 for example
100 = 100(l=1) where l=j+1

---

***HOW DO I LOOP THIS?***

```
for ( i to j?????)

{
spspbold**ll**.**ul** <- tbl_df(bold_specimens(taxon = spsp$BOLDQUERY[ll:ul], geo = "Italy"))

write.csv2(spspbold**ll**.**ul**, "spspBOLD**ll**.**ul**.csv", row.names=FALSE)
}
```

**I appreciate it! <3 <3**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample approach to set the batch size and have R pause between query batches. This should provide a framework to build a solution since the queries can't be replicated. The `na.omit` is used to drop blank values for the last set of queries and is easier than determining the last batch size.

```
df1 <- data.frame(n = seq_len(7030),
                  y = runif(5))

batch_size <- 100
batches <- ceiling(nrow(df1) / batch_size)

df2 <- data.frame() # empty data.frame to load results

for(i in seq_len(batches)) {
  print(na.omit(df1[seq_len(batch_size) + (i - 1) * batch_size, ])) # for illustrative purposes
  df2 <- rbind(df2, na.omit(df1[seq_len(batch_size) + (i - 1) * batch_size, ]))
  Sys.sleep(60) # adjust as needed to not overload the server
}
```

Confirm that the loop builds an equivalent `data.frame` in batches

```
> setequal(df1, df2)
[1] TRUE
```